# jQuery validator addMethod not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using a new validation rule with the jQuery validation.  It is somehow not applied though? It is contained within a javascript file that is included after `jquery.validate.js`.  When should I include the js file that contains my custom rules for them to be applied?

When I enter `0.1` into an input that should validate against this nothing happens, the `console.log` isnt hit neither is the alert.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('integer', function(value, element, param) {
        console.log(value); alert("hey");

        return (value != 0) && (value == parseInt(value, 10));
    }, 'Please enter a non zero integer value!');
});
```

HTML

```
<input class="required number integer valid" type="text" data-type="int" value="1" name="Default.MinArrivals" title="">
```

The classes `required` and `number` work perfectly, it is just my `integer` method that doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Show the corresponding HTML

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to be working for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/2VJZT/

*Please show the rest of your code.*

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('integer', function (value, element, param) {
        return (value != 0) && (value == parseInt(value, 10));
    }, 'Please enter a non zero integer value!');

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                integer: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

> **Quote**:  When should I include the js file that contains my custom rules for
>   them to be applied?

As long as:

1) your code (or file) comes *after* you've properly included `jQuery` and `jQuery Validate plugin` (in that order).

AND

2) your code is all contained within a `document.ready` function.

Notes:  The ordering of `.validator.addMethod` and `.validate()` do not matter with respect to each other as long as you follow 1 & 2.  http://jsfiddle.net/jp93D/

Comment: Hi Sparky.  I still cannot get this working even though I believe mine now follows your example quite well.  Ill update my question with more code

Comment: Aha, interestingly if I alter your fiddle to use class based rules it doesnt work: http://jsfiddle.net/2VJZT/2/

Comment: Edit: I updated your fiddle to work with class based rules (but without errors this time) and it works... What on earth am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/2VJZT/3/

Comment: @Chris, please explain what you mean by "going wrong"?  In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VJZT/2/), you did not define the `integer` rule anyplace.  And in both of your fiddles, you are over-riding the normal `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` behaviors.

Comment: it is all working now thanks, I previously named it `integer` but renamed during testing in case it was a reserved word or something.  Either way your code works. I override normal behaviour as all my forms are dynamically produced, and as such, require class based validation and those rules applied.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem once because I was using the html id rather than the name in the rules.

Might help someone.